# Custom DNS Server with netty - coding the Answer section

Tags: java, dns, netty

I am trying to write a little custom DNS server using netty. The following code works but I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way than using `DefaultDnsRawRecord` to create the DNS answer section? There are some other DNS records like `DefaultDnsOptEcsRecord` or `DefaultDnsPtrRecord` but they seem to be used for other sections of the DNS response.
2. Should I use the netty internal method `io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName()` to create a `InetAdress` object for a fixed IP address without acutally querying the DNS which is required in my case? Is there a standard Java way for this?

Setting up the pipeline:

```
        bootstrap.group(group)
                .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioDatagramChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(NioDatagramChannel nioDatagramChannel) throws Exception {
                        nioDatagramChannel.pipeline().addLast(new DatagramDnsQueryDecoder());
                        nioDatagramChannel.pipeline().addLast(new DatagramDnsResponseEncoder());
                        nioDatagramChannel.pipeline().addLast(new DnsHandler());
                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
                .localAddress("127.0.0.1", 40053);
```

The `DnsHandler`:

```
public class DnsHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramDnsQuery> {

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramDnsQuery query) throws Exception {
    DatagramDnsResponse response = new DatagramDnsResponse(query.recipient(), query.sender(), query.id());

    DefaultDnsQuestion dnsQuestion = query.recordAt(DnsSection.QUESTION);
    response.addRecord(DnsSection.QUESTION, dnsQuestion);

    byte[] address = SocketUtils.addressByName("127.0.0.1").getAddress();
    DefaultDnsRawRecord queryAnswer = new DefaultDnsRawRecord(dnsQuestion.name(),
            DnsRecordType.A, 3600, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(address));
    response.addRecord(DnsSection.ANSWER, queryAnswer);

    ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    cause.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As netty itself not really has any specify encoder / decoder for server side the `DefaultDnsRawRecord` may be your best bet for now.

You should not use classes that resist in the `.internal.` packages as these are for internal usage by netty and may be changed or removed at any time (as these are not considered to be public api). Only use these if you really know what you are doing and not care about breakage.